# Can you be arrested for accidentally signing a recipt for someone else's order?

Tags: criminal-law, fraud, arrest, credit-card

I may have signed a credit card receipt for someone else's pizza order, giving a tip as well. The deliver driver gave my address so I had assumed my aunt or uncle ordered without telling me, then I got the customer receipt with the delivery address on it and it wasn't my address. Can I be arrested for this?

Comment: Who is the "person" in the second sentence - the driver or someone else? Where's the order now? Now that you know the correct address, is there any reason why you can't just take it round and explain the mix-up?

Comment: Me. And this happened last night.

Comment: Okay, but where's the package? Being arrested will depend on whether you intend to keep it, or return it / deliver it to the rightful owner.

Comment: I probably should have clarified it was a pizza order.

Comment: So you, your aunt and/or your uncle ate the pizza?

Comment: What happened to the food? That’s where things get interesting. Anything before you found out it was a wrong delivery would be no big problem.

Answer (score 3):

The primary question is whether you actually committed a crime in signing a credit card receipt, when you are not the cardholder nor are you authorized to sign on behalf of the cardholder: did you commit fraud? It is not possible to accidentally commit fraud, you have to have intended to deceived the other party that you are authorized to sign. For the sake of discussion, I will assume that you had no such intention.

Presumably, the person who ordered the stuff will wonder "where is my stuff?", will complain to the vendor, they may then find the signed receipt and some evidence regarding where the goods were delivered. Whether or not they contact you asking for an explanation / return of the goods, the police would have to investigate the situation in light of some allegation that you committed fraud. The police will not just come knocking on the door and nab you (in the US: North Korean law is different). In many jurisdictions, there is a requirement for a warrant supported by probable cause.

If the investigation provides sufficient credible evidence proving that you did intentionally falsely sign the receipt, to the point that given those facts you would be convicted of the crime, then there is probable cause for a warrant for your arrest. The fact of signing a receipt is not probable cause to support such an arrest, but other facts could be added to reach that level of evidence.

Answer (score 1):

For some reasons, two neighbours get food deliveries and give my address. Direct next door, and three houses further on. Fortunately, I know I didn’t order, and my wife would tell me if she ordered, so I always managed to redirect the deliveries.

So it seems the food company had the right address on the receipt, but the drlivery driver had your address. It was plausible and likely to you that it was a correct delivery to your uncle and aunt.

Signing would be no legal problem, the problem would come after that. What would have been perfect would be to call the food company when you found out, or take the food to the right address if nearby. On the other hand, if you, your aunt and uncle said “Great, free food!” and ate it, that would be a problem.

So what happened to the food? I assume the real customer got refunded; if you are the food you should offer to the food company to pay for it.